# Gitosis and TortoiseGit on Windows

Tags: git, gitosis, tortoisegit

I am having a strange problem with [Gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis) and [TortoiseGit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit).

I used the guide *[How to setup a GIT server with Gitosis and Gitweb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)* to setup Gitosis on my [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) system.

Instead of

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
scp /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ${SERVER_IP}:myuser.pub
```

I used [PuTTYgen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY#Applications) to generate a public/private keypair for my local Windows 7 computer, uploaded it to my server and initialized the Gitosis (same user: git, without a password) with it.

Now I wanted to clone the administrator repository of Gitosis with TortoiseGit (using my private keyfile, `.ppk-file`). It kept asking me for a password for the user "git" - which does not exists. After setting a password for the user "git" the clone-operation resulted in this:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "git@SERVER:gitosis-admin.git" "PATH\gitosis-admin"
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
Initialized empty Git repository in PATH/gitosis-admin/.git/
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

`SERVER` & `PATH` were valid.

How do I solve this? I reinstalled TortoiseGit already with plink-link thingy instead of [OpenSSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. Gitosis can't handle SSH1 keys generated by PuTTYgen. Use OpenSSH keys generated by Git via the console. Check out any tutorial for GitHub for more information on how to do it.